# Can less import file use the `@`?

Tags: javascript, webpack, less

I configured the `webpack.base.config.js` like bellow:

```
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
```

In the abstract, I can use the `import xxx form '@/components/xxx'` to import the file in `<script>`, but whether can I import the `less` file in `<style>` code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to config follow structure of [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader)
and use @import "style/less/file"

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `less` loader of `module->rules` in `webpack`'s config file.

```
  {
    test: /\.less/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      use: ['autoprefixer-loader', 'less-loader'],
      fallback: 'style-loader'
    })
  }
```

and in your `less` code you can import like bellow:

```
@import url('~@/styles/xxx.less');
```